# Проверка корректности пароля

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно выполнить условие "в пароле нет трех одинаковых подряд идущих символов"
То есть если в строку вводишь три одинаковых подряд идущих символов рядом со строкой высвечивается надпись уведомляющая об этом, если нет то надпись что все ок

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так работает, кажется.

```js
const passInput = document.getElementById('pass');
const info = document.getElementById('info');
const btn = document.getElementById('send');
const reg = /([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{2,}/;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(reg.test(passInput.value));
  if(reg.test(passInput.value)) {
    info.textContent = '3 in a row'; 
  } else {
    info.textContent = 'OK';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="pass" type="text">
<p id="info"></p>
<button id="send">send</button>
```